# Sort Pandas MultiIndex that contains str and tuples

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, multi-index

So I have a dataframe with multilevel multiindex where the smaller index is parent and adding a level of index creates the childern that looks something like

```
(a,foo,1)
(a,foo,2)
(a,foo)
a        
(b, foo,1)
(b, bar,1)
(b, foo)
(b, bar)
b
```

and I want to sort the index but when using the sort_index function I receive the following error,
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'tuple'`

Since any index greater than 1 level is stored as a tuple and the single indexes are stored as strings I cannot sort the index.

What is the best approach to have my index become a single datatype so I can sort it?

```
a
(a,foo)
(a,foo,1)
(a,foo,2)
b        
(b, bar)
(b, bar,1)
(b, foo)
(b, foo,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try explode in row then `sort_values` with `na_position`

```
l = df.index
s = pd.DataFrame(l).sort_values([0,1,2],na_position='first').index
df = df.iloc[s]
```

Comment: So the main thing I figured out I needed to do was reset the index before concat the dataframes because the dataframes could not be concatenated with different levels of multilevel index once that was done the sort_values, na_position='first' worked for me. I also had to rename the index once it was down to a single level for the sort values to work correctly

Comment: @DaSchmister glad this help....if so would you like accept and upvote ?